# I have ubuntu installed with mysql .the below error keeps showing up

Tags: mysql, linux, database, ubuntu, vmware

```
linux@ubuntu:~$ mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'linux'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
linux@ubuntu:~$ mysql -u -p
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '-p'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
linux@ubuntu:~$
```

I have ubuntu 14. installed with mysql on a virtual machine vmware .
The above error keeps showing up and I only see the solution everywhere on the internet as :
use "mysql -u -p" but still the error occurs.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It should have space, try this:

mysql -u {username} -p

Answer (score -1):

if you didn't configure mysql(setting password for user), then use just 
     `mysql -uroot`, You should mention username.
You can set password for default user *root* by

```
mysqladmin -uroot password yourpassword
```

after setting password run

```
mysql -uroot -pyourpassword
```

Comment: my username is linux and i typed the following command: "mysql -ulinux"   .But still the same error comes.

Comment: did you tried "mysql -uroot" ? I think *linux* is system/ubuntu username. By default  root is the username for mysql

Comment: I had to create a new user named root and then access through that user.